# SXA Site Manager missing

Tags: sxa, multisite

I want to view the local sites in my SXA site installation. In the following documentation it is mention to use Sitecore SXA Site Manager tool to view what are the SXA sites and if they are accessible or not.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/manage-multiple-sites-with-the-sxa-site-manager.html

But in my instance I can't see SXA Site Manager tool.

Do I have to install any extra package or PowerShell extension to get this in my instance ?

Update: Using SXA 1.8

Comment: What SXA version are you using?

Comment: updated the version in the question

Comment: No extra install needed, it should be in the Powershell Toolbox

Comment: Here is what the official documentation says about locating it: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/manage-multiple-sites-with-the-sxa-site-manager.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can happen if you follow the install guide and install Sitecore Powershell Extensions after installing SXA. When installing SPE, it will prompt about a scripts item already existing. If you selected to overwrite, it will delete the SXA powershell scripts. Instead, select Skip.

To fix this, simply install the SXA package again.